# What a client has to enable to use my app to edit their Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets-api

Let's say I wrote a simple desktop app that reads some data from a Google Sheet, goes off and finds the answer and comes back and writes it into the Google Sheet. Now hundreds of people have sheets and want to use my program to process them. I post my program and let them download it for free.
Here is the sequence I think the end user needs to follow to get it to work:
1. Go to the GCP console and create a new project
2. Enable the Google Drive and Google Sheets APIs
3. Create a credentials JSON file with access as the Project Editor.
4. Create the Sheet if needed.
5. Copy the email out of the JSON file and Share it in the Sheet.
6. Make sure the JSON file is named right and in the right directory so the app finds it.
That all seems like a lot just so an app can read and write to a Google Sheet. Is there a simpler interface I am missing?

Comment: How have you posted your program, are you publishing it in the web store, for example, creating a web app or simply sharing the code? Is this being written in Google Apps Script or is it written locally?

Comment: The program is written in Python. I am distributing a compiled exe for Windows at first. I expect to add more platforms as I test them.

Comment: How is the program reading your credentials? Is it an external file to your exe?

Comment: It has to be external. The credentials are for the end user's Google Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*There are steps that will always need to be completed when a user runs an application that accesses the Google APIs as themself, however depending on the case some of these may be simplified or circumvented.*

#### More information:

There are a few things that you will need to bear in mind when creating an application for others to use, I'll summarise these points here and explain in a bit further detail:

- To use a G Suite API, ***a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project needs to be owned and have the API associated***.
- In order to use the Google APIs (such as Drive and Sheets) ***its use must be enabled within the project that will use it***.
- If a user is running an application as themself, ***they will need to authenticate the application with their own credentials***.

**As per Google's documentation for Setting up a project:**

> Every application that uses Google APIs needs an associated Google Cloud Platform project. This project is a set of configuration settings that define how your application interacts with Google services and what resources it can use.

Resultantly, if your users will be running the application themselves, from a version of the app which is unpublished and not in the G Suite Marketplace then ***yes*** - they will need to create a GCP project, enable the respective APIs and use their personal credential file to run your application.

In reality this isn't the way G Suite Applications should be created, distributed and maintained and I can't reccommend that you do it this way. The G Suite marketplace is there to put in place a way of application distribution while removing the need for each user to create a GCP project and authenticate.

#### Things you can do:

With this in mind, there are a couple of things you can do to which will make the process of what you're doing slightly easier/shorter. Please bear in mind this isn't recommended for application distribution and more for testing purposes:

You can combine points 1, 2 and 3 in your question by having users click the `Enable the Google Sheets API` button on the Python Quickstart page. This button creates a new GCP project, enables the API and gives a credential file download link in one fell swoop.

Rather than having the user create the sheet themselves, you can code a sheet existence check in your program and create it if it doesn't already exist:

```py
from pprint import pprint
from googleapiclient import discovery

# assuming you already have all your authentication code

sheetsService = discovery.build("sheets", "v4", credentials = credentials)

# add request body to variable sheetBody:
sheetBody = {}

# create the sheet:
sheetsService.spreadsheets().create(body = sheetBody).execute()
```

The `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope allows your application to only access files ***created by itself*** which gives your application an extra level of security and trust.

In the `sheetBody` contents you can imclude the email address of the account running the application, if applicable, by running a `Files: list` request of the Drive API and reading the `owners.emailAddress` property of the response, to save reading the address from the JSON file.

#### References:

- **G Suite Developer:**

  - [G Suite APIs](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/aspects/apis)
  - [Set Up Your Project](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/preparing)
  - [Build your app](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/building)
- **Google Sheets API v4:**

  - [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)
- **Google Drive API v3:**

  - [`Files` resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource)